# Purpose of the "I'm making this server for a club or community" when creating server?

Tags: discord

What is the purpose of the checkbox "I'm making this server for a club or community", when you try and create a new server in Discord?

[image: discord server creation dialogue box]

I searched for this exact string on Google, and checked the [Discord help page](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/204849977-How-do-I-create-a-server-) for creating a Discord server, but I couldn't find any answers.

Comment: I think this may be relevant: https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047132851-Enabling-Your-Community-Server. I would guess the difference comes down to whether the server is designated as a community server or not.

Comment: @Ethan Thanks, that'd make sense.

Answer (score 2):

This setting designates it as a **Community Server**

[From the documentation:](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/14078261239831)

> Community Server: Community Servers are invite-only spaces designed for people to share, connect, and learn from others all over the world who share common interests. Moderators in Community Servers have access to tools like Server Insights, Raid Protection, Rules and Onboarding.